# Google App Engine: Failed to load resources using keras/tensorflow/flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-app-engine, flask, keras

I am currently developing a machine learning web application using tensorflow/keras and flask. For deployment I am using Google App Engine (GAE).

Locally I can run my application, get some data via the UI and display the prediction using my laoded models (there are four of them, all .h5 files)

I can deploy it on GAE without any errors but when I enter the link in my browser I get a '502 bad gateway' error and when I inspect the browser (Chrome) I can see three error messages saying 'failed to load resource'.

I am new to web development so I don't fully understand what and where the problem is. Do I need to declare my models in the .yaml file or load them specifically?

My .yaml file:

```
env: flex
runtime: python
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

My main.py file:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.backend import set_session
from utils import instagram_scraper
from utils import image_preprocessing
from utils import label_encoding
from utils import overall_class_label
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

global sess
global graph
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess) 
num_attributes = 4
model = [[] for i in range(num_attributes)]
model[0] = load_model('./model/savemodels/glamorous_model.h5')
model[1] = load_model('./model/savemodels/rugged_model.h5')
model[2] = load_model('./model/savemodels/fun_model.h5')
model[3] = load_model('./model/savemodels/healthy_model.h5')

app = Flask(__name__)


def data_collection(brandname):
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'+brandname+'/?hl=en'
    scraper = instagram_scraper.InstagramScraper()
    official_images = scraper.profile_page_posts(url)
    return official_images


def data_preprocessing(official_images):
    preprocessed_data = image_preprocessing.preprocessing(official_images)
    return preprocessed_data


def make_prediction(preprocessed_data):
    X_test = preprocessed_data

    with graph.tf.compat.v1.as_default():
        tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
        y_pred = [[] for i in range(num_attributes)]
        for i in range(num_attributes):
            y_pred[i] = model[i].predict(X_test)
        y_pred_label = overall_class_label.give_ovr_class_label_output(y_pred)

    # convert from encoded label to label name
    # encoded label
    y_pred_lst = y_pred_label.tolist()
    # map back to original label name
    code2label = {0: 'glamorous', 1: 'rugged', 2: 'fun', 3: 'healthy'}
    y_pred_lbnm = map(code2label.get, y_pred_lst)
    y_pred_lbnm = list(y_pred_lbnm)
    prediction = pd.Series(y_pred_lbnm).value_counts()
    return prediction


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        brandname = request.form["brandname"]
        return redirect(url_for("predict", brandname=brandname))
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/predict/<brandname>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict(brandname):
    official_images = data_collection(brandname)
    preprocessed_data = data_preprocessing(official_images)
    prediction = make_prediction(preprocessed_data)
    return render_template("predict.html", prediction=prediction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```

My app structure:

```
parent
 --model
   --savemodels
     fun_model.h5
     glamorous_model.h5
     healthy_model.h5
     rugged_model.h5
 --static
     style.css
 --templates
     index.html
     predict.html
 --utils
     image_preprocessing.py
     instagram_scraper.py
     label_encoding.py
     overall_class_label.py
 app.yaml
 main.py
 requirements.txt
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!
All the best,
snowe

Comment: I understand your concerns.The 502 errors could be caused by many reasons. To get more information, Could you please share the Stackdriver Logging for the 502 Errors from your Cloud Console.

Comment: Hi Nibrass, thank you for your response! When I try to deploy it now it tells me that my quotas are exceeded. So I do not have access to the log files. Is it possible that the .h5 files are too large to get a response from the browser in time? They are each about 150MB.

Comment: If someone knows how to deploy such an application on Microsoft Azure, I am more than happy to try it out there :) I was able to successfully deploy the same application from a local git repo to a remote azure repo but when I click on the URL I get an error '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'.

Comment: As far as I understand I need to do it via a local git repo because the models I use are too large to upload to GitHub (there are four models, each around 190MB). Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, I understand that your concerns. As the error mentions, you are trying to load too many resources or you have a lot of files. Could you please share the complete error to see whether it is due to what I said previously ? If this is the case, you will need to open a Google Cloud Platform Support Ticket and ask to increase your quotas for App Engine Flexible, but first, as I said, please share the complete error?

Comment: but how can I access the complete error if I can't get my application running because I am out of quotas?

Comment: Your application is not running because it gives you quota exceeded errors. You can see the complete error in Stackdriver logging for App Engine or you can share what you see when you deploy.

Comment: not sure what you are talking about tbh. i cannot deploy hence i have no logs to show.

Comment: AS you mentioned, when you try to deploy you get quota exceeded errors. Please could you provide that full error in the post? Thanks

Comment: Hi Nibrass, in the meantime I switched to Microsoft Azure and started building my application from scratch to see where the problem is. I found out that the application crashed because of too many resources. As I managed to downscale it and get a working pipeline I will no longer work on GAE. But thank you for your advice and help! :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks to let me know, but you can also do the same in GCP just you had to increase the number of resources for App Engine as it was giving the quota exceeded error.